# Java - Replace all occurences of '${' in string

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java 1.8 to iterate over a file which contains variables defined like this.

```
<var name = "QUEUE_PREFIX" value = "TEST/QUEUE/PREFIX"   />
<var name = "IN_QUEUE"     value = "${QUEUE_PREFIX}/IN"  />
<var name = "OUT_QUEUE"    value = "${QUEUE_PREFIX}/OUT" />

<element>${IN_QUEUE}</element>
```

which should result in

```
<var name = "QUEUE_PREFIX" value = "TEST/QUEUE/PREFIX"     />
<var name = "IN_QUEUE"     value = "TEST/QUEUE/PREFIX/IN"  />
<var name = "OUT_QUEUE"    value = "TEST/QUEUE/PREFIX/OUT" />

<element>TEST/QUEUE/PREFIX/IN</element>
```

The replacement of these variables is done in memory using this code.
Note that I replace the variables inside of the variable declarations part first, before continuing with the replacement in the main part of the document.

```
private static final String VAR_START = "\\$\\{"
private static final String VAR_END   = "\\}"

private String fileContent = readFile(path);
private Map<String, String> variables = getVarsFromFile();

private void replaceInVariables() {
   for(Entry<String, String> e : variables.entrySet()) {
      fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll(VAR_START + e.getKey() + VAR_END, e.getValue);
   } 
}
```

I am receiving the following error from this

`named capturing group is missing trailing '}'`

**My Question:**

How do I escape the "${" and "}" as a literal string so that it does not use it as a regexp?

Comment: You probably need `fileContent.replaceAll(VAR_START + Pattern.quote(e.getKey()) + VAR_END, Matcher.quotereplacement(e.getValue))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer. I had to use the Pattern.quote(); around the whole statement. But in the end the more important part was the Matcher.quoteReplacement. because it was possible that a variable already referenced a variable in which case it would try to replace with ${something}.

Comment: Yes, as I thought. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the dynamic (user-defined) replacement that may contain `${` without `}` and thus the regex engine will think there is a corrupt named backreference.

You may keep the delimiters without manual escaping, and rely on [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to escape the whole regex pattern, and on [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to escape the replacement pattern:

```
private static final String VAR_START = "${";
private static final String VAR_END   = "}";

// ...

fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(VAR_START + e.getKey() + VAR_END), Matcher.quoteReplacement(e.getValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different approach? Matching all occurences of `${...}` and then replacing them in a callback. This looks more straightforward and more efficient than replacing the string multiple times.

With Java 9 it is something like this:

```java
Map<String, String> variables = …;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}");
String replaced = pattern.matcher(your_input_string)
        .replaceAll(mr -> {
            String placeholderName = mr.group(1);
            // fall back to placeholder when not defined:
            return variables.getOrDefault(placeholderName, mr.group(0));
        });
```

Here's a working demo example: https://ideone.com/3XxRk4